# Connect to MariaDB with localhost from Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

First of I did read thoses links

- [Connect to Docker MySQL container from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost)
- [Connect to Mysql on localhost from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897077/connect-to-mysql-on-localhost-from-docker-container)
- [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

But as a beginner with docker. It did not help me.

What you need to know:

- Yes, **I need localhost**. I'm working on an app that interact
  directly with the database. It create/remove user privileges and
  allow some user to access with limited privileges from a remote
  access. When initialized, the app will drop the default remote access to root and forge user and grant them full privilege on localhost.
- I'm using a **docker-compose.yml** generated by https://phpdocker.io
- Ubuntu 18.10
- Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
- docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown
- I'm using docker only for development purpose. On production I use [forge](https://forge.laravel.com)

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
###############################################################################
#                          Generated on phpdocker.io                          #
###############################################################################
version: "3.1"

services:

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
      container_name: myapp-mailhog
      ports:
        - "8081:8025"

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: myapp-redis

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.4
      container_name: myapp-mariadb
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp
        - MYSQL_USER=forge
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=forge
      ports:
        - "8083:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: myapp-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: myapp-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

**./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


    root /application/public;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

**./phpdocker/php-fpm/Dockerfile** *(slightly modified to add mysql_client and not installing git in a second RUN command)*

```
FROM phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  \
        php7.3-mysql php-redis php7.3-sqlite3 php-xdebug php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-gd \
        git \
        mysql-client \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

**./php-ini-overrides.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 108M
```

I tried to use `network_mode: host` but it makes the webserver stopping with `Exit 1`

Comment: Where does the constraint that it _must_ be `localhost` come from?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you need access to mysql thru the local unix socket and you will not allow access true TCP/IP? Guess that is what localhost means in MariaDB

Comment: @DavidMaze The PHP (Laravel project) I'm working on as migration files that setup the database. It executes SQL that create a `root@localhost`, `forge@localhost`,  delete `root@%` and revoke/grant privileges on `forge@%` and during the application lifecycle, it will create, drop users etc.. The reason we drop access to `%` is because your clients need a readable remote access on some views. But we don't want users with high privilege to be accessible from remote.

Comment: @F.Madsen From **webserver** I need to connect to **mariadb** with `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` and `mysql -u forge -h localhost -p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok but as remember it, localhost in mysql/mariadb means access thru the local unix socket. There are ways of sharing these between containers.

Have a look here [Connection between docker containers via UNIX sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637587/connection-between-docker-containers-via-unix-sockets)

Comment: Thanks! But how does it work with docker-compose? Here's what I tried: `docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock busybox` in an another terminal: `docker-compose up -d` then `docker exec -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) myapp-php-fpm /bin/bash` and finally in the container `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` but I got `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: I also tried to replace `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` with `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  with no success. (Sorry, I'm not familiar at all with docker)

Comment: Then it'll not be easy... Basicly you need to create a folder on your local host that will hold the socket-file. Then you mount this folder in both the mariadb and the web container. That will be in the "volumes:" sections of your compose yml file. Doing so, you will effectively create the db socket on you local filesystem. Also make sure that the privileges on the socket is right.

Comment: I make it works! Thank you very much! I will make an additional answer on how exactly I did it.

Comment: Great, if you are nice to the docker whale, it'll be nice to you :)

Comment: Is it possible to archive the same with `networks`? I really don't want to store the socked on my host. There must be a way to tell docker to expose mariadb to php's localhost. It's just a different port.

Answer (score 0):

@F.Maden gave me the right direction. I accepted his answer but here's how I made it in details.

Basically has he said, I need to share **mysqld.sock** between my services **mariadb** and **php-fpm**

1. The first step is to share a folder between both services. Since I already
   have `/application` that contains the docker config `/application/phpdocker`, I will reuse this one.
2. I had to create a custom my.cnf file to edit the default **mariadb** config configuration and add a custom socket path:

**./phpdocker/mariadb/my.cnf**

```
[mysql]
socket = /application/phpdocker/shared/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /application/phpdocker/shared/mysqld.sock
```

3. Then I had to share the config file with my mariadb container

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
  mariadb:
  image: mariadb:10.4
  container_name: myapp-mariadb
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - .:/application
    - ./phpdocker/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf # notice this line
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp
    - MYSQL_USER=forge
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=forge
  ports:
    - "8083:3306"
```

4. I created a folder `./phpdocker/shared` with privileges 777 where mariadb will be able to create **mysqld.sock** *(I couldn't start mariadb with 755. In my case this is only used on local not on production so it's fine)*

**From the terminal**

```
$ mkdir ./phpdocker/shared && chmod 777 ./phpdocker/shared
```

---

### And now test it!

**From the terminal**

```
$ docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
$ docker exec -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) myapp-php-fpm /bin/bash
```

**Once in the container**

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost --socket=/application/phpdocker/shared/mysqld.sock
$ mysql > select user();

+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Great and clear description. You can avoid the 777 privilege problem by creating a unix group, eg. dockergrp with a specific GID. X . Then you do the same in all your images and make sure the users created in the containers are granted a group with a GID X. unix/linux is special while it does not care about the name of a group, only the GID. Now 770 is enough. The same group can be used generally for all containers running.

Comment: @F.Madsen Thanks for the tip! I will definitely make that. I have learned at LOT on docker with that question and now you're already answering me what the next question I had in mind. Again, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem with connection to DB persists:

We can interogate what IP DB container has:

```sh
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name>
```

We'll receive container IP (eg: 172.21.0.3);

After this, we can place this IP into connection "host" section.

Enjoy!

Ref [How can I access my docker maria db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170489/how-can-i-access-my-docker-maria-db)